# Display 3 div next to each other

Tags: css

I have three divs with an complete length of 150% but i dont get them to float in one line:
Here is my html:

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="left" id="w1">TEST</div>
<div class="left" id="w2">TEST</div>
<div class="left" id="w3">TEST</div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
html,body { height:100%;width:auto;}

.left {
float: left;

}
  #w1 {width:20%;
 background-color:#009;
  }
#w2{width:100%;
  background-color:#9F3;
 }
#w3{ width:30%;
background-color:#30C;}
```

Here is the full code on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sZwXN/1/
Besides his it would be nice if each panel has an height o 100%!

Comment: no, i want the full length greater than 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 3 div in a row then you will use float:left with all div, but you can not take 150% width in a total of div width.
You can take 100% maximum.
So, Adjust your width of all div and take total 100%.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `float: left` by `display: table-cell`, and putting the three divs into an other one with `display: table` and `width: 150%`, rather than trying to trick with `float`.

Thus, by updating your code like this, you get what you are looking for :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left" id="w1">TEST</div>
  <div class="left" id="w2">TEST</div>
  <div class="left" id="w3">TEST</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
.wrapper
{
  display: table;
  width: 150%;
}

.left {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

And changing your `#iw` width to respectively `14%`, `66%`and `20%` to keep the ratio you are looking for.

Have a look : http://jsfiddle.net/sZwXN/7/

Answer (score 1):

The 3 divs are greater than the width of their parent. You need to adjust them so their widths total is less than or equal to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

total width should not exceed 100%. **in your case 150% so make ratio same with 100%. like 20% of 150% = 12% approx** and so on...

html,body { height:100%;width:auto;}

```
.left {
float: left;

}
#w1 {width:12%;
background-color:#009;
}
#w2{width:70%;
background-color:#9F3;
}
#w3{ width:18%;
background-color:#30C;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sZwXN/4/

Comment: then you can set parent width:150% but keep these div's total not more than 100%, keep them same ratio

Answer (score 0):

```
To have in one line reduce the width of w2

#w2{width:50%;
  background-color:#9F3;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this css and html

**HTML**

```
<div class="left" id="w1">TEST</div>

<div class="right" id="w3">TEST</div>

<div id="w2">TEST</div>
```

**Css**

```
html,body { height:100%;width:auto;}

    .left {
    float: left;

    }
    .right{float:right;}
    #w1 {width:20%;
    background-color:#009;
    }
    #w2{
    background-color:#9F3;
    }
    #w3{ width:30%;
    background-color:#30C;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/sZwXN/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

floated elements break lines when there's no space for them in the width
since your second div is 100%, there will never be space for him with other elements that have width in the same horizontal

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the semantic, not in the code.

Percentage values always refer to the outer, "father" element with an width defined, or to the viewport, or to the HTML.

If you say a div has `width: 100%;` , it means it would be as large as the containing element.

It doesn't matter if you say the html/body are 10000px, or 200% wide: the div will have the same width, because, guess what... it is 100% wide.

The question is **really** *mis-asked* ... Try reformulating by specifying what you are **really** trying to achieve.

<sub>Otherwise, you would need Chuck Norris. He counted to infinity. Twice. I guess he can count to 150%.</sub>