# 3 divs next to each other with span

Tags: html, css

I try to put 3 div-s in one line like answers in this topic: [Display 3 div next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716597/display-3-div-next-to-each-other)

But this isn't workinkg in my case. Maybe the span is problem in my case.

I need this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8ky0.jpg

But get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LjqZ.jpg

```css
.followers, starred, following {
  display: table-cell;
}

#w1 {width: 10px;
background-color:#009;
}
#w2{width: 10px;
background-color:#9F3;
}
#w3{ width: 10px;
background-color:#30C;}
```

```html
<div id="git-info">
    <div class="followers" id="w1">
        <span>10.4k</span><br>Followers
    </div>
    <div class="starred" id="w2">
        <span>1</span><br>Starred
    </div>
    <div class="following" id="w3">
        <span>5</span><br>Following
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in

```
.followers, starred, following {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

this should be

```
.followers, .starred, .following { /* note the preceding dots to indicate class */
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```css
.followers, .starred, .following {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="git-info">
  <div class="followers" id="w1">
    <span>10.4k</span><br>Followers
  </div>
  <div class="starred" id="w2">
    <span>1</span><br>Starred
  </div>
  <div class="following" id="w3">
    <span>5</span><br>Following
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float: right;` or `diplay: inline-block`

```
#w1 {width: 10px;
background-color:#009;
float: right;
}
#w2{width: 10px;
background-color:#9F3;
float: right;
}
#w3{ width: 10px;
background-color:#30C;
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#git-info {display:flex;}

#git-info div {flex:1;}
```

This will also give all 3 divs the same height & width

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using table structure like, main git-content is display:table, then children are display:table-cell; 
see below snippet.

```css
div#git-info {
    display: table;
}
.followers, .starred, .following {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
#w1 {
  background-color:#009;
}
#w2{
  background-color:#9F3;
}
#w3{
  background-color:#30C;
}
```

```html
<div id="git-info">
    <div class="followers" id="w1">
        <span>10.4k</span><br>Followers
    </div>
    <div class="starred" id="w2">
        <span>1</span><br>Starred
    </div>
    <div class="following" id="w3">
        <span>5</span><br>Following
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

div uses `display:block` by default due to which it always comes in next line.

to overcome this you can either assign float property

(`float:left;` or `float:left`)

or you can use

`display:inline-block`

so in your case you should use

```
.followers, starred, following {
  display: table-cell;
  float:left;

}
```